# Load JS file in Master Page (ASP.NET, VB.NET)

Tags: javascript

UPDATE

I got rid of the errors but the JS still dosen't work.

In the MasterPage head section I have this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container_menu").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
    });
</script>
```

When inspecting the page in the browser I get these warnings and errors:

> jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'left'
>   of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
>        at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost:64093/js/script.js:2:31)
>        at l (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29375)
>        at c (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29677)
>   undefined w.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2 jquery.min.js:2 
>   jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).sticky is not a function TypeError: 
>   $(...).sticky is not a function
>        at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost:64093/:17:30)
>        at l (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29375)
>        at c (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29677)
>   undefined w.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2 jquery.min.js:2 
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
>        at HTMLDocument. (script.js:2)
>        at l (jquery.min.js:2)
>        at c (jquery.min.js:2) jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sticky is not a function
>        at HTMLDocument. ((index):17)
>        at l (jquery.min.js:2)

ORIGINAL POST

*I'm trying to link a js file from /js/file.js in the head section of a master page. I tried everything I found on the internet with no luck. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/jquery.sticky.js" />
```

The error I got is having something to do with the JS code in my opinon. Here's what I got:

```
 BC30035: Syntax error.
          Line 1:  (function (factory) {
          Line 2:      if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
          Line 3:          // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
```

Comment: You shouldn't have `runat="server"` in there.

Comment: I deleted that, I haven't got any errors now but the JS is still not working...

Comment: try to load without type=""  ->  <script src="~/js/jquery.sticky.js" />
and maybe you could post some info about the error. and maybe use a newer jquery version: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: where in your tree is your masterpage and where is the js file excactly? Could be something wrong with the path

Comment: master page is in the root and the js file is in the js folder.

Comment: try to add <base href="/"> to the beginning of your head

Comment: Nothing happens...

Comment: In your browser, open the developer tools (F12) and find the network tab. Clear it if there is anything shown. In the browser window, refresh the page (F5). Go back to the network tab and look for where it loads jquery.sticky.js - if it has an HTTP response code of 200 or 304 then it was loaded into the browser, otherwise you need to find out why it was not delivered to the browser.

Comment: Status code: 200

Comment: If I put the whole java script code in my master page file, everything works perfect.

Comment: Make sure the jQuery can find the element: put something like `if ($("#container_menu").length) {alert("found");}` after `$(document).ready(function(){`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a trick: Open the master page and the Solution Explorer. Drag the .js file from Solution Explorer into the head of the master page and try again.

Comment: Sounds like you need to post a separate question on this one Ryan. But there is one thing you could check: the code in this JS file might not be taking into account the 'form' added to every page by the master page. So maybe the jQuery selectors in that js file need to be tweaked? Best of luck :)

Comment: Thanks mate. I'm going to ask another question then.

Comment: @RyanP. If you haven't discovered it, you can press F12 in (most) browsers to get "developer tools". There will be a console which will show errors and a network pane which will let you see if the JS file actually got loaded.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, that's my problem. I can see the <script src=""> in the page source in the browser and they have the correct path. If I click on the file url the file will be opened in the browser so the path and syntax I think they are all spot on but still, acting like there's no JS file. I got no errors and not warrnings about the JS.